# Facebook Like Button - change font color?

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to change the color of text in a Facebook like button? Besides selecting a different color scheme, I don't see a way to adjust the font...

Comment: Is this post related to some Facebook-API?

Comment: Their new social plugins: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like

Mikulas below answered my question.

Comment: http://members.chello.nl/~sgm.jansen/facebook-button-colorizer/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook has not released this feature yet. However, you may change it using javascript - when using the JS based version, not iframe.

Comment: Do you mean the XFBML-version? If so the <fb:like>-tag still renders an iframe, which is inaccessible to the host page because of cross site scripting limitations, so how is this accomplished?

Comment: @mikulas-dite Can you please add a sample code? -I cannot figure out how to alter it with js.

Answer (score 3):

Facebook retains control over their button and only allows you to set predefined options for skinning it. As font color goes, you can choose the light colorscheme to go with light backgrounds, or the dark colorscheme to go with dark backgrounds.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

Answer (score 3):

**YES**

It can be done

[image: Red Facebook Like button]

**NO**

It's probably not allowed by Facebook's [brand guidelines](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/branding).

**Demonstration**

I created a [demo page](http://members.chello.nl/~sgm.jansen/facebook-button-colorizer/) that lets you pick the colors using a slider or palette, or that lets you manipulate the filter directly.

[image: Demo page: Facebook button colorizer]

**Background information**

The technique basically works by applying a hue-rotate filter to the element containing the i-frame. Hue-rotate sort-of rotates a color wheel. As such we can't give the button any color we want. We are limited to the 360 degrees of rotation we can apply to the default button. But there are some greens, browns, reds, pink and even purple we can play with. Try it out for yourself.

**References**

[StackOverflow: how to change color of facebook like button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095946/how-to-change-color-of-facebook-like-button)

[Stijn de Witt's Blog: Change the facebook button color](http://stijndewitt.wordpress.com/2014/02/22/change-the-facebook-button-color/)

Answer (score 2):

Include data-colorscheme="light/dark" according to your background in the div with class "fb-like". Light color scheme is for light background and vice-versa.