# how to customize facebook like button?

Tags: facebook

i have an image and i want it to be the like button on the page.

how can i do that?

Comment: See my response on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095946/how-to-change-color-of-facebook-like-button/4096415#4096415

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. This is strictly prohibited. Facebook like buttons can only be the official buttons. Additionally, there is no public API for creating likes.