# Facebook Like Custom Font Color and Image

Tags: facebook, image, colors, facebook-like

i was searching many internet resources to find out how to change the FACEBOOK like button custom image and font color. Could not find any valuable resources. Can any one help me out in this problem??

Comment: Facebook doesn't really want you tampering with their designs.  If you could change the color you would be one step closer to changing the text from "like" to "un-like" and that's just confusing.  I recommend you leave Facebook design alone.

Comment: A big part of the success of the "like" button and Facebook itself is the familiar feeling that users get when using a Facebook or Facebook related site.  All the colors and buttons are similar... A like button will always be a like button.  This is very important to  maintain a consistent user experience.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another question that is pretty similar to what you are asking: [how to change color of facebook like button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095946/how-to-change-color-of-facebook-like-button)

And here is a reference guide for the Facebook Like button:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Sounds like it's probably not possible to change the color of the Like button text, at present.  But, you can change the color scheme between "light" or "dark" themes, according to the links above.

Search is your friend. :)