# Changing css of facebook like button's side description

Tags: jquery, css

I want to change css of description on right hand side of like button. I've tried css and jQuery but I don't find any solution.
[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Fpf94)

HTML / CSS

```
<div id="fbLike">
 <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Flivehelpdotcom&amp;width=130&amp;layout=standard&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=true&amp;share=false&amp;height=80&amp;appId=194262817314403" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:130px; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
</div>


#fbLike { background:blue;padding:40px}
```

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, you can't affect the style on an iframe. Try using like-button with HTML5.

Comment: HTML5 isn't working as well

Comment: With HTML5, have you tried using this: `#fbLike { background:blue !important;padding:40px !important}`?

Comment: I'm seeking to change an element dynamically generated within that iframe

Comment: I would check out this thread discussing the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095946/how-to-change-color-of-facebook-like-button